# Excel Add-In cellFormat for multi lingual audience

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

When writing data to excel either using a binding or using the current selection like it's required to use correct number formats depending on the content language.

So the following code fails if content language is english.

`const options = {
  cellFormat: [{cells: {row: 1}, format: { numberFormat: '#.###,00'}}]
};
Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(tableData, options);`

an ugly solution would be for example

`const options = {
  cellFormats: [{
    cells: { column: 3 }, 
    format: { 
     numberFormat: Office.context.contentLanguage.startsWith('de')?
        '#.###,00': '#,###.00' }
   }];
};
Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(tableData, options);`

Is there no abstract format like `currency`, `number` or something like users know form excel's UI?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure, but what if you tried using the "new" (Office 2016) wave of APIs.  Something like:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
    var sheetName = "Sheet1";
    var rangeAddress = "F5:G7";
    var numberFormat = [[null, "d-mmm"], [null, "d-mmm"], [null, null]]
    var values = [["Today", 42147], ["Tomorrow", "5/24"], ["Difference in days", null]];
    var formulas = [[null,null], [null,null], [null,"=G6-G5"]];
    var range = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheetName).getRange(rangeAddress);
    range.numberFormat = numberFormat;
    range.values = values;
    range.formulas= formulas;
    range.load('text');
    return ctx.sync().then(function() {
        console.log(range.text);
    });
}).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
});
```

Example taken from https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/range

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. Although it's a little bit different approach.

Comment: Do let us know if the new approach works better than the old one, so that we can file an appropriate bug at that time.